# Maximum time Intervel for NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer, nstimeinterval

In our application we have to auto log out user if he doesn't logged in for a week.

What is the best method to schedule it? I used `NSTimer` with time interval of (24*7*60*60) will it work?.

> NB: Login screen will automatically shown after terminating the app. So the case occurs only when the app is minimized for a week

Comment: I'm pretty sure that setting the timer to a week would technically work, except that it will be released and thus will not fire when the app is closed.

Answer (score 3):

NSTimer gets paused when app is in the background. There is every chance that your user to run other apps, so your app will go to the background.

I would tackle the problem like this

- When user login, I take the current time (`NSDate` )  and save it in
  `NSUserDefault` with a key like "lastLoginTime".
- Whenever user starts/resumes the app I check the current time with
  previously saved time. If the difference is greater than 1 week, I
  call logout.
- If difference is less that 1 weak, I update the `NSUserDefault` value
  with current time.